Livewire status changing
There is a button that works with Livewire. When I click on it, it changes the status of the given license, but when I click on it, the appearance and the database change, but I can't click on that button again.
public function changeStatus($license_id, $status)
{
    License::where('id', $license_id)->update(['status' => $status]);

    return session()->flash('status-message','Sikeresen megváltoztattad a license státuszát!');
}

public function render()
{
    $this->licenses = $this->getLicenses();

    return view('livewire.license-manager', [
        'licenses' => $this->licenses
    ]);
}

private function getLicenses()
{
    return License::query()
        ->with(['users' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('role', 'owner');
        }])
        ->when($this->search, function ($query) {
            $query->where('key', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                ->orWhereHas('users', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('role', 'owner')
                        ->where('email', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%');
                });
        })
        ->get();
}

<button
    wire:click="changeStatus({{ $license->id }}, '{{ $license->status == 'active' ? 'inactive' : 'active' }}')"
    wire:loading.attr="disabled"
    key="{{ $license->id . '-' . $license->status }}"
    class="{{ $license->status == 'active' ? 'border-orange-500 hover:bg-orange-600' : 'border-black hover:bg-gray-700' }} border-2 text-black hover:text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg transition">
    {{ $license->status == 'active' ? 'Blokkolás' : 'Feloldás' }}
</button>


How do you render these buttons, in a loop?

public $isProcessing = false; 

public function changeStatus($license_id, $status){
            // Prevent multiple clicks during processing
            if ($this->isProcessing) {
                return;
            }
    
            $this->isProcessing = true; // Set the flag to true during processing
    
            License::where('id', $license_id)->update(['status' => $status]);
    
            $this->isProcessing = false;
    }

Blade:
<div>
    <!-- Button to toggle the license status -->
    <button wire:click="changeStatus"
            wire:loading.attr="disabled"
            :disabled="$isProcessing"
            class="btn btn-primary">
        @if ($license->status)
            Deactivate License
        @else
            Activate License
        @endif
    </button>

    <!-- Loading indicator while processing -->
    <div wire:loading>
        Processing...
    </div>
</div>


$isProcessing: This variable is used to track whether the status
change is still in progress. The button will be disabled while
$isProcessing is true and re-enabled when it's false.

wire:loading.attr="disabled": This ensures that while the Livewire
action is processing, the button is automatically disabled.

:disabled="$isProcessing": This ensures the button is disabled on the
client side when $isProcessing is true.



This solution has no effect, as the $isProcessing variable is returned only at the end of processing, so it will always be false
